# add columns dynamically in jquery data table and insert data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a json like this

```
{
  Date: "2017-11-07",
  Items: [
 {
   count: "160",
   period: "0",
 }
 ]
 },
 {
  Date: "2017-11-08",
  Items: [
  {
   count: "106",
   period: "0",
  },
  {
    transCount: "298",
    period: "1",
    tranType: "new"
  }
 ]
 },
```

For every date I want to create a new column and insert 'count' value of items array in that column.
so far I have done this

```
 $("#dtable-users").append('<table id="dtchurn" class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead></thead><tbody id="tbody"></tbody></table>');
      for(i=0; i<= jsonStr.length;i++)  
      {   
         var tableColumn = "<th> " + jsonStr[i].Date + "  </th>";
         $("#tbody").append(tableColumn)

         for(j=0; j < jsonStr[i].Items.length;j++)
         {
           var tablerow = "<tr><td>"+ parseInt(jsonStr[i].Items[j].transCount) +"</td></tr>"
           $('#tbody').append(tablerow);
         }  
    }
```

I'm having problem in adding columns, my columns are also inserting as rows.
[image]

Comment: Could you please show the real JSON? The above is an excerpt from something larger, at least the begging and the end of the JSON should be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#dtable-users").append('<table id="dtchurn" class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead></thead><tbody id="tbody"></tbody></table>');
  var tbl_head = '',tbl_rows=''
  for(i=0; i<= jsonStr.length;i++)  
  {   
     var tableColumn = "<th> " + jsonStr[i].Date + "  </th>";
     tbl_head + = tableColumn;

     for(j=0; j < jsonStr[i].Items.length;j++)
     {
       var tablerow = "<tr><td>"+ parseInt(jsonStr[i].Items[j].transCount) +"</td></tr>"
       tbl_rows + = tablerow;
     }
     if(i===jsonStr.length-1)
     {
        $("#tbody").append(tbl_head);
        $('#tbody').append(tbl_rows);
     }
}
```

Comment: Try this but i haven't tested it